# matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg is throwing an attribute error for 'blit'

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

When I try to run `python3 module_7.py` on my terminal, I get the following error:

```
  File "/opt/CarlaSimulator/PythonClient/live_plotter.py", line 227, in plot_figure
    tkagg.blit(photo, fca.get_renderer()._renderer, colormode=2)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg' has no attribute 'blit'
```

I have checked the matplotlib installation and everything seems fine.  This problem arises when using the CARLA simulator.  There were a couple of suggested fixes like adding the backend_tkagg import before the pyplot import but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that matplotlib has changed some things.
According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_tkagg_api.html) you should use `tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg.blit` instead of `tkagg.blit` (assuming that you `import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg`).

Answer (score -1):

As of October 2022, if you are setting up the CARLA simulator for the Intro to Self-Driving Cars course on Coursera, the answer is to downgrade `matplotlib` from 3.x.x to 2.2.2:

I got the following answer from a [post](https://www.coursera.org/learn/intro-self-driving-cars/discussions/forums/p7tlc1PxEeijBgoMqGXeNg/threads/BeY0koyfTsCmNJKMn17A_Q/replies/qYbEj75qRT6GxI--alU-Ew/comments/gBgCQjhLQEeYAkI4S4BHwA) by Achyutha Krishna Rao Kothapalli on Coursera.

```
1) python -m pip uninstall matplotlib (if you have matplotlib 3.x.x installed)

2) python -m pip install matplotlib==2.2.2 (install matplotlib 2.2.2)

3) Use "import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg" instead of "import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg" in the live_plotter.py
```